# getting error in commnad prompt while migration in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql-9.2

I am new to ruby and rails
while  writing rails generate migration migration_name i get the following error

```
 c:\Sites\employee>rails generate migration initial_schema
      invoke  active_record
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse': (<unknown>):
 couldn't parse YAML at line 8 column 2 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse_s
tream'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:125:in `parse'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:112:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:507:in `next_migration_number'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/rails/generators/active_record.rb:21:in `next_migration_number'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb:49:in `migration_template'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb:10:in
`create_migration_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:109:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:278:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/shell.rb:74:in `with_padding'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:267:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:150:in `_invoke_from_option_orm'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/generators.rb:171:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\Sites\employee>rake db:create
rake aborted!
(<unknown>): couldn't parse YAML at line 8 column 2

Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

C:\Sites\employee>rails generate migration initial_schema
      invoke  active_record
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse': (<unknown>):
 couldn't parse YAML at line 4 column 2 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse_s
tream'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:125:in `parse'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:112:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:507:in `next_migration_number'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/rails/generators/active_record.rb:21:in `next_migration_number'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb:49:in `migration_template'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.11/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb:10:in
`create_migration_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:109:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:278:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/shell.rb:74:in `with_padding'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:267:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:150:in `_invoke_from_option_orm'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/generators.rb:171:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
1/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\Sites\employee>
```

Comment: `couldn't parse YAML at line 8 column 2` may be you'll post the YAMl file

Comment: You "database.yml" may not be correct. May be some spacing or comma issue. Try loading that YAML file in rails console and see if the same error is coming.

Comment: Please post `database.yml`

Comment: there is something wrong with your `config/database.yml`

Comment: # postgresql v0.8.x
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding:unicode
  host:localhost
  database: employee_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
   username:postgres
  password:prath123

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding:unicode
  host:localhost
  database: employee_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
   username:postgres
  password:prath123

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding:unicode
  host:localhost
  database: employee_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username:postgres
  password:prath123

Comment: this is the yaml code.pls help me

Comment: @RamandeepSingh even if i run it in rails console the same error is occuring.

Comment: it was the yaml spacing which needed to b checked.now its working fine

Comment: Cool ! Now dat u figured it out !